# Mocking Celery `self.request` attribute for bound tasks when called directly

Tags: django, unit-testing, celery

I have a task `foobar`:

```
@app.task(bind=True)
def foobar(self, owner, a, b):
   if already_working(owner): # check if a foobar task is already running for owner.
       register_myself(self.request.id, owner) # add myself in the DB.
   return a + b
```

How can I mock the `self.request.id` attribute? I am already patching everything and calling directly the task rather than using `.delay/.apply_async`, but the value of `self.request.id` seems to be `None` (as I am doing real interactions with DB, it is making the test fail, etc…).

For the reference, I'm using Django as a framework, but I think that this problem is just the same, no matter the environment you're using.

Comment: This doesn't make sense. Is that task part of a class? If so, show it; if not, it wouldn't have a `self`. And in any case, a task does not run as part of a request, so why would there be a `self.request`?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Did you already use Celery? If not, please read this beforehand: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#bound-tasks ; the decorator is wrapping the function in a class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Disclaimer**: Well, I do not think it was documented somewhere and this answer might be implementation-dependent.

Celery wraps his tasks into `celery.Task` instances, I do not know if it swaps the `celery.Task.run` method by the user task function or whatever.

But, when you call a task directly, you call `__call__` and it'll push a context which will contain the task ID, etc…

So the idea is to bypass `__call__` and Celery usual workings, first:

- we push a controlled task ID: `foobar.push_request(id=1)` for example.
- then, we call the run method: `foobar.run(*args, **kwargs)`.

Example:

```
@app.task(bind=True)
def foobar(self, name):
    print(name)
    return foobar.utils.polling(self.request.id)

@patch('foobar.utils.polling')
def test_foobar(mock_polling):
    foobar.push_request(id=1)
    mock_polling.return_value = "done"
    assert foobar.run("test") == "done"
    mock_polling.assert_called_once_with(1)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can call the task synchronously using

```
task = foobar.s(<args>).apply()
```

This will assign a unique task ID, so the value will not be None and your code will run.  Then you can check the results as part of your test.

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a way to do this with `patch`, but I could not work out a way to assign a property. The most straightforward way is to just mock self.

**tasks.py:**

```
@app.task(name='my_task')
def my_task(self, *args, **kwargs):
    *__do some thing__*
```

**test_tasks.py:**

```
from mock import Mock

def test_my_task():
    self = Mock()
    self.request.id = 'ci_test'
    my_task(self)
```